# Why assign global variable to value inside a callback function in node js return undefined in console?

Tags: node.js, callback

Take this example

```
var s;
cb = function(error,result){
s = result;
}
memcached.get('hellow',cb);
console.log(s);
```

This give me `undefined`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The answers on this question so far have been great; I wanted to mention that you may be interested in this screencast, which covers this exact issue: http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log(s);` line executes before the `cb` function does because `cb` isn't called by `memcached.get` until `result` is available.  This is the classic asynchronicity that occurs with any I/O operation in node.js.

Comment: yes, but how i could get the `s` value outside callback function?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.  Any code that relies on the result of the `memcached.get` must execute after the callback is called.  So you can put your code that references `s` in the callback, or use a flow control library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to execute another function after `cb` is called.

Comment: To cut a long story short: You can't - at least not without additional helpers such as the already mentioned `async` module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute `console.log` after defining `s` because it asynchronous:

```
var s;
cb = function(error,result){
    s = result;
    console.log(s);
}
memcached.get('hellow',cb);
```

Comment: good but is there is another way to get `s` value outside callback function?

Comment: call external function, emit event or wait some time with setTimeout (not the best way)

Answer (score 1):

The variable **s** is being initialized within a call back function. This call back function will get triggered only when memcached.get() completes getting the data for 'hellow'.

Javascript reliesy on the event loop mechanism. This means that the javascript runtime will continue executing the script until it reaches the end without blocking for any callback to occur.

As a result in your example, the javascript runtime will execute the line **console.log(s)** immediately after the line **memcached.get('hellow',cb)** without blocking. Hence console.log(s) in your case will print a valid value (other then **undefined**) only if the **cb** has executed prior to the last line.

Please move the line **console.log(s)** within the call back function for more consistent results.

Comment: it seams that this is the only way to achieve result